# Naudio AsioOut convert from and to float (VST.NET)

Tags: c#, arrays, audio, naudio, vst

I'm working on a project where i'm trying to get audio from a asio audio driver, convert the audio into the VST.Net float array (2 channel float array with values ranging from -1 to +1).
What i'm doing for that is this:

```
   void asio_DataAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
    {     
        float[] farr = new float[e.SamplesPerBuffer*2];
        e.GetAsInterleavedSamples(farr);

        for (int p = 0; p < e.SamplesPerBuffer; p++)
        {
            vstBufIn[0][p] = farr[p];
            vstBufIn[1][p] = farr[p];
        }

        cont2.PluginCommandStub.ProcessReplacing(vstBufIn, vstBufOut);
        byte[] bytebuf = new byte[vstBufOut[0].SampleCount * 4];
        int j = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < vstBufOut[0].SampleCount; p++)
        {
            float f = vstBufOut[0][p];
            byte[] temparr = new byte[4];
            temparr = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)(f * (float)Int32.MaxValue));
            bytebuf[j] = temparr[0];
            bytebuf[j + 1] = temparr[1];
            bytebuf[j + 2] = temparr[2];
            bytebuf[j + 3] = temparr[3];
            j += 4;
        }
        Marshal.Copy(bytebuf, 0, e.OutputBuffers[0], bytebuf.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(bytebuf, 0, e.OutputBuffers[1], bytebuf.Length);

        e.WrittenToOutputBuffers = true;
     }
```

The asio_DataAvailable function is called when the asioOut's buffer is full and needs to be processed. This code is for testing purposes mainly focused on working and is as a result ignoring the second channel at vstBufOut.

The input coming from the AsioOut when i just do Marschal.Copy to get it into a byte array is:

```
0
(some number)
251 (and sometimes 250, 252 or 253)
255
0
(some number)
251 (and sometimes 250, 252 or 253)
255
.... (and so on)
```

so it seems like it's maybe 24 bit little endian???

The result of this code is: I get audio which roughly sounds like the sound coming in though it is disturted. I had a similar problem when i tried it before with WaveIn where i didn't correctly converted the 16 bit mono array from waveIn into vstBufIn and vstBufOut back to WaveOut.
So i tried the things i did back then but none of them seemed to work:

1. I tried: vstBufIn[0][p] = farr[p]; vstBufIn[1][p] = farr[p + 1]; p++; to alternate...
2. I tried changing the Int32.MaxValue to 2^23 to get the Max value of 24bit Integer but this just made it more quite to not hearable
3. I also messed around with the sizes of the arrays and the max values of the for loops but this seems at least to me be the most logical version...

Does someone has an idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The samples you retrieve from Asio are interleaved. That means that one L sample is followed by a R sample followed by a L sample etc. So a small change in your first loop should enable you to split the interleaved Asio buffer into distinct L and R channels.

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://vstnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/122820

Comment: Thank you for comment. Again after reading all the information and trying out all your tips like interleaving the array, looking at what sample type i'm getting from asio and then fixing some logical bugs i produced myself i now got it working like a charm. Thank you again so much obiwanjacobi :)

Comment: May i also ask how i could combine different audio/arrays to one output? I don't want to open up a new question for this probably small topic.
The reason i'm asking:
In my program i will get the audio input then send the resulting array to several vst plugins. In the end i want to combine all of the sound arrays coming from the plugins in one asio output.

Comment: just add the samples together, applying a gain for each source. For instance: (sampleSrc1 * 0.5) + (sampleSrc2 * 0.5). Reduce each source by half and then add them together. But I am not a DSP guru...